# Correspond table column to subsequent worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make it so that in my table in the sheet list of Assets which begins on cell A5 corresponds with the subsequent worksheets afterwards. So once a value in the column A is changed the worksheet change events triggers. So the first sheet after "List of Assets" has cell A5 name and so on. Code not working and I'm really stuck. Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NextSheetName As String
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Define the range of cells to monitor for changes (e.g., column A from A5 to the last row)
    Set KeyCells = Me.Range("A5:A" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is within the monitored range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Then
        ' If a change is detected, run the renaming macro
        
        ' Set the initial sheet as "List of Assets"
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List of Assets")
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sheet 'List of Assets' not found.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Set the starting cell as A5
        Set StartCell = ws.Range("A5")
        
        ' Loop through each cell in column A of "List of Assets" and rename sheets
        For i = 3 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2 ' Start from the third sheet
            NextSheetName = StartCell.Value
            Debug.Print "Renaming sheet to: " & NextSheetName ' Debugging message
            On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = NextSheetName
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Error renaming sheet '" & NextSheetName & "'.", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Set StartCell = StartCell.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to the next cell in column A
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify "not working"? Do you get an error (which error number and text, on which line) or does the code not perform as expected (what is different compared to expected result)?

Comment: the code doesn't work as ended no errors appear. when I change the values in column A nothing happens. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Rename Worksheets By Index

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Define constants.
    Const FIRST_CELL_IN_COLUMN As String = "A5"
    Const THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX As Long = 1 ' > 0 < 'Worksheets.Count'
    Const FIRST_WORKSHEET_INDEX As Long = 3 ' > THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX
    Const DEBUG_PRINT As Boolean = True
    
    ' Objects
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Me
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
     
    ' Validate inputs.
    If THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX >= wsCount Then
        If DEBUG_PRINT Then
            Debug.Print "The index of this worksheet (" & THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX _
                & ") needs to be less than the number of worksheets (" _
                & wsCount & ")!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If Not sws Is wb.Worksheets(THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX) Then
        If DEBUG_PRINT Then
            Debug.Print "This code needs to be in worksheet " _
                & THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX & "!"
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX >= FIRST_WORKSHEET_INDEX Then
        If DEBUG_PRINT Then
            Debug.Print "The index of the first worksheet (" _
                & FIRST_WORKSHEET_INDEX & ") needs to be greater than " _
                & "the index of this worksheet (" & THIS_WORKSHEET_INDEX & ")!"
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the intersecting (changed) cells ('sirg').
    
    Dim srg As Range, RowIndexOffset As Long
    
    With sws.Range(FIRST_CELL_IN_COLUMN)
        Set srg = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        RowIndexOffset = .Row - FIRST_WORKSHEET_INDEX
    End With
    
    Dim sirg As Range: Set sirg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    If sirg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Rename.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, scell As Range, sVal As Variant
    Dim dwsIndex As Long, dwsName As String
    Dim CouldBeValidName As Boolean, WasRenamed As Boolean
    
    For Each scell In sirg.Cells
        ' Worksheet
        dwsIndex = scell.Row - RowIndexOffset
        If dwsIndex > wsCount Then ' too few worksheets; index too high
             If DEBUG_PRINT Then
                 Debug.Print "Cannot rename worksheet " & dwsIndex _
                     & " because there are only " & wsCount & " worksheets!"
             End If
             Exit Sub
        End If
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dwsIndex)
        dwsName = dws.Name
        ' New Name
        sVal = scell.Value
        If IsError(sVal) Then
            sVal = scell.Text
        Else
            If Len(sVal) > 0 Then CouldBeValidName = True
        End If
        ' Rename.
        If CouldBeValidName Then
            If dwsName <> sVal Then ' case-sensitive
                On Error Resume Next
                    dws.Name = sVal
                    WasRenamed = Err.Number = 0
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
        ' Log.
        If DEBUG_PRINT Then
            If WasRenamed Then
                Debug.Print "Renamed """ & dwsName _
                    & """ to """ & sVal & """."
            Else
                Debug.Print "Not renamed """ & dwsName _
                    & """ to """ & sVal & """!"
            End If
        End If
        ' Reset.
        WasRenamed = False
        CouldBeValidName = False
    Next scell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it did not work :(